# Two potatoes in container are bad -- are the remaining potatoes affected?

Tags: diseases, potatoes

I'm growing potatoes in containers. I just turned out one container to harvest the potatoes. Two of the potatoes were gelatinous and foul, as in the photo:

[image]

### Update: these *weren't* the seed potatoes, which I did find in the container.

However, the rest of the potatoes look and feel right, as below:

[image]

Are the remaining potatoes safe to eat? And why were only two of the potatoes in that state?

Comment: The two "decaying" ones might have been the potatoes you originally planted. If the others look and smell OK, I would be happy to eat them. It you want to be cautious, cut them into pieces to check for anything nasty inside when you cook them, rather than cooking them whole.

Comment: I should have clarified: these were not the seed potatoes.